# Fast Multiplication Code in C

Tags: c

I am studying multiplication source code and I don't understand this function for multiplying `x*A`.  Please help me to understand this with any numeric example please?

```
#define BITS_PER_LONG (8 * sizeof (unsigned long))

typedef struct matrix{
int rown;//number of rows.
int coln;//number of columns.
int rwdcnt;//number of words in a row
int alloc_size;//number of allocated bytes
unsigned long *elem;//row index.
}*binmat_t;

void mat_vec_mul(unsigned long *cR, unsigned char *x, binmat_t A)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned long *pt;

    memset(cR, 0, A->rwdcnt*sizeof(long));
    pt = A->elem;
    for(i=0; i<A->rown; i++)
    {
        if ((x[i/8] >> (i%8)) & 1)
            for (j = 0;  j < A->rwdcnt;  ++j)
                cR[j] ^= *pt++;
        else
            pt += A->rwdcnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide declarations of `binmat_t`.

Comment: I found the binmat_t as a pointer to a struct:                    Data Fields

int  rown
int  coln
int  rwdcnt
int  alloc_size
unsigned long *  elem

Comment: Here: https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/MCE/structmatrix.html Google is a good source ;)

Comment: It looks like a matrix-vector multiplication routine for use with McEliece crypto calculations:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem, discussed in this thesis: http://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/Gerhard_Hoffmann.bachelor.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a vector of bits, which are stored in an array of char. The number of bits in x is A->rown. The expression `(x[i/8] >> (i%8)) & 1` selects the i<sup>th</sup> bit of x.

A is a two-dimensional array of unsigned long, with A->rown rows and A->rwdcnt columns.

cR is a vector of unsigned long with A->rwdcnt elements. cR is cleared upon entering this routine.

The `if` statement determines whether the i<sup>th</sup> bit in x is on. If the bit is on, then the i<sup>th</sup> column of A is “added” to cR. If the bit is off, then the `else` clause skips this column of A. Since a bit can have only values of 1 or 0, this `if-else` is equivalent to multiplying the column of A by the bit and adding the product to cR.

The “addition” is done by XOR. The interpretation here is unclear. It may be that each cR is a single array of bits (and each column of A), or it may be that each unsigned long in cR (and in A) represents a polynomial over the integers modulo two. (This is a common type in cryptography.)

I suspect that cR is a single array of bits, and that A->rwdcnt = A->coln / BITS_PER_LONG.

Effectively, this is a standard array multiplication over the integers modulo two.

Comment: how I can print the cR in bits in the screen?

Comment: @Juan: People usually find it sufficient to print hexadecimal with the “%x” conversion in printf (or some variant, such as “%08x” to print eight digits with leading zeroes). If you want explicit binary, you will need to write your own routine to convert an unsigned long to a binary numeral and print it.

Comment: I am trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149259/multiply-over-finite-field-p-2, I think that in this "sum" is the error ...

Comment: whats is the function of *pt++?

Comment: @Juan: `pt` points to the `elem` data. `*pt++` evaluates to the value that `pt` currently points to then increments `pt` to point to the next item.  `cR[j] ^= *pt++;` is more or less equivalent to `cR[j] = cR[j] ^ *pt; pt++;`