# Multiply over Finite field p=2

Tags: c

Using this [Fast Multiplication Code in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146052/fast-multiplication-code-in-c) code I am trying to multiply `x*A` where `x=0xAA` and `A` this matrix

```
1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0  1 0 1 1  0 0 0 1  0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0  0 1 1 0  1 1 1 0  1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1  1 1 0 1  1 0 1 1  0 0 0 0
```

but in the C compiler I don't get nothing, my program it is hung.

Why happens this? any idea?.

I think that issue is in this line

```
cR[j] ^= *pt++;
```

Comment: The compiler is hanging, or your program is hanging?  I'd be very surprised if the compiler were hanging.

Comment: my program, sorry by my english

Comment: Of course you should post your code if you want any help.  sscce.org